# How to stop an onended function onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have an onclick shuffle function that executes everytime the audio finishes. It works all fine, but I want to  make another button that stops its execution.

Please please help with an example

Full Code:

```
<button onclick="test();stats();auto()">Shuffle</button>

<button id="abort" onclick='exitauto()'>Stop Shuffle</button>
<script>

function exitauto(){
  

}

</script>

<script>
function stats() {
if(document.getElementById("audio").src == "test.mp3")
{
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "some song";
 document.getElementById("playerimg").src="img.png";

   };
}

</script>

<script>
function auto(){
var aud = document.getElementById("audio");
aud.onended = function shuf() {
    test();
    stats();
    };
}

</script>
<script>

function test() {
    var values = ['test.mp3',  
 ],
        
        valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];

  document.getElementById("audio").pause();
     document.getElementById("audio").setAttribute('src', valueToUse);
     document.getElementById("audio").load();
     document.getElementById("audio").play();
     
  };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a global variable which can be used to decide whether to call the test() and stats() function in the auto function or not. You can set that variable to true when clicked on start and false when clicked on stop